# jquery mobile backbutton to quit App for specific Page

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I had a look around and can't seem bind the backbutton to a specific page for Android phone in Phonegap/JQM.

I am trying to only allow the backbutton to trigger `navigation.notification.confirm` to prompt the logout at 1 specific page. But it either doesnt prompt it or prompt it every single page.

This below doesn't trigger

```
$(document).on( 'pageinit','homepage',function onLoad(){
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
            }
        function deviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener('backbutton', backButtonCallback, false);
        }

        function backButtonCallback() {
            navigator.notification.confirm('Do you want to exit the app? If not, use the top left button to go to Previous Page',confirmCallback);
            }
        function confirmCallback(buttonIndex) {
            if(buttonIndex == 1) {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
            return true;
            }
        else {
            return false;
            }
        })
```

This doesn't trigger either

```
function onLoad(){
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
            }
        function deviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener('backbutton','#homepage' backButtonCallback, false);
        }

        function backButtonCallback() {
            navigator.notification.confirm('Do you want to exit the app? If not, use the top left button to go to Previous Page',confirmCallback);
            }
        function confirmCallback(buttonIndex) {
            if(buttonIndex == 1) {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
            return true;
            }
        else {
            return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 getActivePage() can be handy.  $.mobile.activePage was deprecated in JQM 1.4.0 (see http://blog.jquerymobile.com/  Changes since 1.4.0 beta #deprecation).

```
//handle Back button
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    console.log('Device ready - register onBackKeyDown()');                
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    var active_page = $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" );
    var id =active_page.page().attr('id');
    if (id==='homepage') {
        if (confirm('Do you want to exit the app? If not, use the top left button to go to Previous Page?')==true){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    }
    else{
    navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
}
//**
```

This code will exit app only if activePage id is homepage.

Tell me if code works for you.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try right now, but i am using 1.4.4 tho. I will just download the 1.4.5 and give it a try

Comment: ! It works!! Thanks so much!! I want to upvote for you but i dont have enough points yet

Comment: @John Did worked with 1.4.4? Deprecation occurred since version 1.4.0 beta, so I believe that method is available with 1.4.4 too.

Comment: I looked up on the 1.4.4 documentation and i searched for the activePage function, i didnt see anything for it. But it is in the 1.4.5 documentation, so i just switched my 1.4.4 to 1.4.5.